# Embed image/icon within Tooltip ChakraUI or CSS in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am attempting to embed an image/icon into my tooltip via the Chakra UI library. So that it is more that just the label showing, I want the **MdWarningAmber** Icon to show in the tooltip rather than next to the button to hover over

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/tooltip/usage

```
<Tooltip label=' Access to this page is exclusively available to registered users.'
    className="tooltip"
    aria-label="tooltip"
    placement='right-end'
    closeDelay={100}
    bg={"white"}
    textColor={"#8e8e8e"}>
     <span>
      <Icon as={MdWarningAmber} color={"#8e8e8e"} />
         <Button>
             Hover Over Me
         </Button>
     </span>
</Tooltip>
```

I have tried placing a  with the Icon inside but that doesnt seem to help

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation mentions:

> ### label
>
> Description: The label of the tooltip
> Type: ONLY_FOR_FORMAT = | string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal

```
<Tooltip label={(<div>
  <WarnIcon />
  <p>Access to this page is exclusively available to registered users.</p>
</div>)}
    className="tooltip"
    aria-label="tooltip"
    placement='right-end'
    closeDelay={100}
    bg={"white"}
    textColor={"#8e8e8e"}>
     <span>
      <Icon as={MdWarningAmber} color={"#8e8e8e"} />
         <Button>
             Hover Over Me
         </Button>
     </span>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is using the **<Popover>** element and adding `trigger="hover"`